# Why while input from user information I must use getchar before using fgets

Tags: c, c-strings

When I try to acquire input from the user, I require using fgets() right after getchar as described here:

```
while (getchar() != '\n'); //Check's if we entered
fgets(new_book_string, NAME_LENGTH-1, stdin); //input the book the user want to borrow
```

Why? Is there more effective method to scan a string ?

Comment: Why do you think this is inefficient?

Comment: It's require to iterate through getchar()....

Comment: that skips only one `\n` what if we enter more than one `\n`s

Comment: I've already have a solution for this @IrAM p_s[strlen(p_s) - 1] = 0

Comment: No, I meant what if we enter several new lines before entering any input

Comment: afterthe first newline it's automaticially goes